# Why are some emoji not displayed?

Tags: fonts, text-input, emoticons

I am wondering, on what does it depend which emoji are available on which system? I was using an emoji from the **Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs** code page and it displays on OSX, but not on Android. Looking at the chart from [the Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supplemental_Symbols_and_Pictographs), I can see that it displays in full on OSX, but only some of the emoji are visible on Android Nougat.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the NotoColorEmoji.ttf font file you have installed. If that file doesn't include a glyph for the Unicode code point you want, it can't show it. Here's an SO post about fonts and glyphs:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582944/how-does-a-unicode-character-get-mapped-to-a-glyph-in-a-font

This reddit post talks about replacing your system's NotoColorEmoji.ttf font file with one that includes [EmojiOne](http://emojione.com/) emojis:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/3xezb9/emojione_on_android/